# Trunc date in shell?

Tags: shell

I need to transform the current date in seconds but the current date must be first  truncated to midnight.

```
From 2018-05-25 13:30:30 to 2018-05-25 00:00:00.
```

Is there an equivalent for `trunc(sysdate)` from `oracle`?

Comment: `date +'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date` on the `shell` to achieve this.

```
date -d "2018-05-25 13:30:30" "+%F 00:00:00"
```

which will output

```
2018-05-25 00:00:00
```

Here is a version which uses date twice to first get todays date truncated and then turns it into epoch seconds.

```
date -d "`date '+%F 00:00:00'`" "+%s"
```